# User Summary page does not list users

Tags: openfire

I am developing an iPhone app using Openfire as my server.

When I create new users in Openfire, I can see how many I created in the User Summary (JSP) web page, but in the user list part, it's empty! I can NOT see the user information, the only way to check the info is to use the user-search.

My Openfire Version is 3.8.2, and my MySQL version is 5.6.12. Sometimes loading the index can be very slow too. Before I'm asked this, I've tried Nightly Build version and re-installed Openfire several times, but the problem was not solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the version of the MySQL, when I change MySQL to 5.1 version, everything is ok now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your version of MySQL server version the same, follow the answer given here.

http://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/49738